# How to show image stored in database to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, asp.net, json

I have created an SP for getting image from database as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spGetItemImage @Id AS INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT ItemImage1,ItemID,CompanyID
FROM ItemImage
WHERE ItemImage.ItemID = @Id 
END
```

ItemImage1 is received as byte[250]. I have a div for receiving image from database `<div id="imgUpload">`. I have a Json for displaying image in div. Here image is received in the form of byte code. So it cannot display any image on the div. I have done so far is:

```
document.getElementById("imgUpload").src = "data:image/png;base64," + (data.d.ItemImage1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think You Should Convert Your Byte Array into Image Like

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

then Save that image to Particular Location Map images using
Like `Server.MapPath("~\\UploadImages")`
and Show in Div

and for vice versa You can try:
Convert Image to byte[] array

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
 return  ms.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function something like

```
public function DisplaySavedDBImage()
{
//get Image from DB (as per your code base... this is just an example)
    $model=$this->loadModel($_POST['Pic']['id']);



    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-length: '.$model->file_size);
    header('Content-Type: gif');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$model->file_name);

        echo $model1->file_name;
}  and <?php echo CHtml::link('image',array('displaySavedDBImage','id'=>$model->primaryKey)); ?>
```